# How to I add a custom event to a plugin

Tags: jquery, html, events, plugins

Problem I have a plugin for a button that takes a link and makes it act like a submit button.  But I want to perform an action before the form is submitted.  Since the click binding is done in the plugin that click event if fired before the click event bound on the page changes a hidden input.

I am thinking that I would like to add a custom event or event listener that can be fired in the plugins click event.  I can then put attach my controls to this event so that it will set the hidden input value before it fires off.

Here is a chunk of my plugin code.

```
////////////////////////////////////////
// Object initialization and teardown //
////////////////////////////////////////
init: function (options, element) {
    this._super(options, element);
},

bind: function () {
    this.element.delegate("", "click",
        $.proxy(this.click, this));
    this.element.delegate("", "preSubmit",
        $.proxy(this.preSubmit, this));
},

unbind: function () {
    this.element.undelegate("", "click", this.click);
},

////////////////////
// Helper methods //
////////////////////
click: function (e) {
    var form = this.element.closest("form")[0];
    this.preSubmit();
    if (form)
        form.submit();

    e.preventDefault();
},
preSubmit: function(e){
    alert("Hi Moe");
}
```

Now in my pages I would like to be able to use the preSubmit to perform an action before it gets submitted.

My page code is something like this:

```
    $("#SuggestEdit").preSubmit(function () {
        alert("just a test2");
        $("#SuggestedAddressAction").val("Edit");
        alert($("#SuggestedAddressAction").val());
    });
```

So In Pseudo Code: 
When button is clicked fire off the preSubmit event and for me and do something if it is there otherwise continue with the click event funtionality.

Comment: `$("#SuggestEdit").on('preSubmit'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a plugin with a custom event following these steps.  I will show this by creating a submit button that will raise a preSubmit event prior to submitting the form.

Step one Create an EventHandler on the base object

```
preSubmit: function (e) {
    alert("parent presubmit");
}
```

Nest in the stand bind event handler bind the events:

```
bind: function(){
    this.element.delegate("", "click", $.proxy(this.click, this));
    this.element.delegate("", "preSubmit", $.proxy(this.preSubmit, this));
},
```

Now to ensure that this event is fired when the button is clicked but before the form submits it must be raised in the Click Event Handler:

```
click: function (e) {
    var form = this.element.closest("form")[0];
    this.element.trigger("preSubmit"); //<--
    if (form)
        form.submit();
    e.preventDefault();
},
```

Now that the plugin has both a click handler and a preSubmit handler you need to attach this plugin to an element on the page.  There are multiple ways to do this but this version is pretty common and is part of boilier plate plugin controls I have seen:

```
   $.plugin('button', Myplugin.Common.Control.mybutton);
```

On the page that needs this functionality for instance a page that is submitting data but needs to set a hidden form value prior to submitting the form (*that was my problem.  NOTE: my issue was that the binding for the click event for the plugin was fired before the click event was fired.  So the form submitted before the click event handler on the page could change the value*).

On the page all you need to do is set up an event handler for the preSubmit event and do your work to the values in the form in there.

```
 $("#mybutton").on('preSubmit', function(){
            $("#MyName").val("modified value");
        })
```

Now the plug in will fire off a new event that will be processed prior to the form submitting.

Here is my plugin control full code (besides the base classes.  I am using SimpleInheritance.js from By John Resig http://ejohn.org/)

```
Myplugin.Common.Control.mybutton = Myplugin.Common.Control.extend({

name: "my_button",

init: function (options, element) {
    this._super(options, element);
},

bind: function(){
    this.element.delegate("", "click", $.proxy(this.click, this));
    this.element.delegate("", "preSubmit", $.proxy(this.preSubmit, this));
},

unbind: function () {
    this.element.undelegate("", "click", this.click);
    this.element.undelegate("", "preSubmit", this.preSubmit);
},

click: function (e) {
    var form = this.element.closest("form")[0];
    this.element.trigger("preSubmit");
    if (form)
        form.submit();
    e.preventDefault();
},
preSubmit: function (e) {
    alert("parent presubmit");
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will work,

```
$(document).off("preSubmit", "#SuggestEdit").on("preSubmit", "#SuggestEdit", function () {
    alert("just a test2");
    $("#SuggestedAddressAction").val("Edit");
    alert($("#SuggestedAddressAction").val());
});
```